# Elixir fetching key/value pair from json/struct

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Being new to Elixir and functional programming I'm having some problems to fetch the "taste" key from this struct.

```
json = response.body
icecream = Poison.decode!(json, as: %{"items" => [%Icecream{}]})

Returns:
[%{"items" => [%MyModule.Icecream{size: "Large",
 taste: "Pistachio"}]}]
```

I would like to only get the taste ("Pistachio") saved to a variable in the most optimized way.

I'm looking forward to be enlightened. :)

Solution:
I came up with this myself:

```
taste = List.first(icecream["items"]).taste
```

Comment: The approach you should choose will depend on how you want edge cases. What do you want to happen when the element isn't there (if you care to handle that case)? Would you prefer it to raise an exception or return nil? Something else?

Comment: I expect it to always be there, but I agree that it would be nicer with a check on it.

Answer (score 2):

Using pipes, you can do

```
icecream |> hd |> Map.get("items") |> hd |> Map.get(:taste)
```

However, I suggest you use [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2) in conjunction with [`Access` helpers](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#module-accessors), which IMO results in very readable code and seems nicer for more complex cases.

```
import Access
get_in icecream, [at(0), key!("items"), at(0), key!(:taste)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get a compiler error on the second solution though: undefined function at/1

Comment: Did you `import Access`? You can also do it local to a single function if you are concerned about cluttering your namespace.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Is that only available in certain versions of Elixir?  Perhaps Zahrec is working with an older version of Elixir?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci good catch! It seems this was added in 1.3.x

Comment: I'm running Elixir version 1.3.4

Comment: I hadn't seen the import at first. After having improted the Access module I'm met with the error: "Access.at/1 expected a list, got: [%MyModule.Icecream{size: "Large",
 taste: "Pistachio"}]}]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simple pattern matching:

```
[%{"items" => [%{taste: taste_val}]}] = your_result
```

It saves `taste` value into a variable `taste_val`. If your result doesn't have a `taste`, it will be set to `nil` (or your default value) as you use module with `defstruct` where you define a structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Map.get` or `Map.fetch`
See: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#fetch/2)

Bear in mind, if you are using

`Map.fetch!(map,key)`

you can cause a side effect (error thrown) when the key is not present in `map`. If you are using `Map.fetch(map,key)` you will get back a tuple with either **ok** or **error** status, signifying the availability of `key` in `map`.